# How to upload RDF to server without storing it in DB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, temporary-files

In our application, we have to upload RDF files to our Glassfish application server to infer them and load them in our graph DB.

For that, immediatly after upload, we start by storing their raw content into our graph. This is clearly non optimal, as our graph is a neo4j one, optimized to store small objects (and not nodes containing strings of 25 MB).

So, to perform long tasks (and as a consequence not during request/response cycle), how to store those files temporarly in a JavaEE6 server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual knowledge is that storing files in JavaEE is bad, as access to file is by nature non transactionnal.

Unfortunatly this is false : [XADisk](http://xadisk.java.net/) is a Java library allowing transactionnal access (even allowing XA transactions) on file system. using it, it's very easy to create/read/delete files in JavaEE transactions.